# Why suddenly I started getting No query results for model error in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I don't know why I started getting the following error while working on Laravel application.

`No query results for model [App\Hotspot].`

Here is my Model Function to get user's hotspots.

```
public function hotspots()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Hotspot::class, Operator::class, 'id', 'operator_id');
}
```

and here is how I am executing the query to get data.

```
$hotspotId = $id;
$hotspot = Auth::user()->hotspots()->findOrFail($hotspotId);
```

I started getting this error suddenly. I don't know what went wrong! I tried to find solution on internet but they are totally different cases.

Comment: it would appear that there are no longer any hotspots related to that user.  Did you verify in the database that a related item exists?

Comment: Hey @bizzybob, I figured it out that with every request, ID `1` is passed instead of actual ID. I don't know what's wrong I am very much frustrated.

Comment: Try this: `$this->hasManyThrough(Hotspot::class, Operator::class, 'user_id', 'operator_id', 'id');` and check if it works...

Comment: I have another same relationship. That is working totally fine.

Comment: @BizzyBob and @Laerte , My code is working fine for id `1` but not working for others.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships, section Has Many Through.

```
return $this->hasManyThrough(Hotspot::class, Operator::class, 'user_id', 'operator_id', 'id');
```

This is necesary due to you are first connecting the Hotspots to he User, after that you are connecting he operations to the Hotspots. therefor his order is correct.

Reason for it working certain times, is because of id clashes, if you used Uuids this code would never work. You can also debug this solution with he following.

```
DB::enableQueryLog();

// General i feel like Auth::user()->hotspots->where('id', $hotspotId)->first() is more Laravel'sh.
// Like this you will query a lot, if used in wrong cases.
$hotspot = Auth::user()->hotspots()->findOrFail($hotspotId);

dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

Or you can get the raw sql, sometimes provides you with a different view.

```
dd(Auth::user()->hotspots()->toSql());
```